# INSERT IGNORE mysql insert id gaps when writing to unique index workaround

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use `while $1<=N` loop to get database row from table `TTT` and run certain operation with it, rinse and repeat. I use `$i` to retrieve the next consecutive id row from database on each loop go.

I used to run `SELECT` query to find the duplicates in table `TTT`, but now with current size of `TTT` it is too slow, so I decided to go with `Unique index`.

Everything works fine and no more duplicates, however there are now gaps in my `id` values because I use `INSERT IGNORE`, which breaks my script depending on `id`'s to be consecutive.

So how do I adjust my code to get the same functionality with `unique index`?

I was thinking to create temp table with ordered ids, but that was bad idea.I was trying to get next id in previous loop go with `(id > $i)`, but it would only work for first gap...

Comment: what about sharing this secret code with us ...?

Comment: its a basic code involving the operators mentioned in description, anyway I just found the soulution

Comment: Why do you care if there are gaps?

Comment: because I depend on consecutive incrementation of id value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so for my situation where only one script inserts into TTT, my solution is to enable

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
```

to get the desired functionality back.

More info on different ways to handle the issue - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html